# Java Program to read, union and save data

Tags: java, union

I am very new to `Java` and i would appreciate your help in the thema that i am trying to solve. I would like to program a small `Java` program that can:

1. read data (tables)
2. `union` them by row
3. display them in the frame
4. download the file

I got to the point where I am not sure if the code I wrote is actually productive and I got stuck at displaying the data.
I have prepared a small example of two data files:

**car**

```
Row Description Type Example
1 Name String XX
2 Year int 2021
3 Value double 0.37
4 Area double 2.84
5 Weight double 1000
6 Tyre String 210/10 R1
```

**motor**

```
Row Description Type Example
1 A String XY
2 B double 230
3 C int 1000
4 D int 3400
5 E int 1000
```

You can find my `Java` code, which at the moment is able to open dialog, select the file with `JFileChooser`, display the path and read the data (1). I got stuck with displaying the `union` of two tables and downloading the file. Thanks for any help!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JFileChooserExample extends JPanel {
    // use a list model and JList that works *directly* with Files
    private DefaultListModel<File> fileListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<File> fileJList = new JList<>(fileListModel);
    List<String>  kfz_list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String>  motor_list = new ArrayList<>();
    static Path filePath;
    static Path filePath2;
    static Path car;
    static Path motor;

    public JFileChooserExample() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new SelectFilesAction("Select Files", KeyEvent.VK_S)));

        // help set the width and height of the JList
        fileJList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        fileJList.setPrototypeCellValue(new File("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(fileJList);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private class SelectFilesAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SelectFilesAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(JFileChooserExample.this);
            if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileListModel.clear();  // clear the model of prior files
                 File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                 for (File file : files) {
                     // add all files to the model
                     boolean matches = Pattern.matches(".*car*.", file.getPath());
                     boolean matches2 = Pattern.matches(".*motor*.", file.getPath());
                     if(matches) {
                         car = file.toPath();
                     }
                     if(matches2) {
                         motor = file.toPath();
                     }
                     System.out.println("car path");
                     System.out.println(car);
                     System.out.println("motor path");
                     System.out.println(motor);

                     Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                     // car read ans instantiate

                     try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = Files.newBufferedReader(car, charset)) {
                         String line;
                         while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                             // System.out.println(line);
                             kfz_list.add(line);
                         }
                     } catch (IOException ex) {
                             System.out.format("I/O error: %s%n", ex);
                         }

                     Kfz kfz1 = new Kfz();
                     //kfz1.Kfz("A", 2015, 23.5, 2.3, "B", 12.0);
                     kfz1.Kfz(kfz_list.get(0), Integer.parseInt(kfz_list.get(1)), Double.parseDouble(kfz_list.get(2)), Double.parseDouble(kfz_list.get(3)), Double.parseDouble(kfz_list.get(4)), kfz_list.get(5));

                     System.out.println("checking kfz1");
                     System.out.println(kfz1.getName() + " " + kfz1.getBaujahr());

                     // motor read and instantiate
                     try (BufferedReader bufferedReader2 = Files.newBufferedReader(motor, charset)) {
                         String line2;
                         while ((line2 = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null) {
                             // System.out.println(line2);
                             motor_list.add(line2);
                         }
                     } catch (IOException ex) {
                             System.out.format("I/O error: %s%n", ex);
                         }

                     Motor motor1 = new Motor();
                     motor1.Motor(motor_list.get(0), Double.parseDouble(motor_list.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(motor_list.get(2)), Integer.parseInt(motor_list.get(3)), Integer.parseInt(motor_list.get(4)));
                     System.out.println("checking motor1");
                     System.out.println("Bezeichnung: " + motor1.getBezeichnung() + " " + "Max_drehmoment: " + motor1.getMax_drehmoment());
                         // end
                     fileListModel.addElement(file);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
            JFileChooserExample mainPanel = new JFileChooserExample();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Example");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should have enough experience here to know that you should only ask one question. You are asking several.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! My previous experience shows to document the question very well and stating clear the problem. i wanted to put together all the challenges in this small programm that i would like to have...But You are right, i could have divide this question...

Comment: Your question relates to several problems. First you have to create some JTables which list the data in rows and columns and then it depends on your selection which row and wich column are chosen before any further processing can be worked out. A lot of works.

Comment: @Joe thanks for answer. Well as i mentioned i am very new to java. Can i ask you a question what do you mean by selection of row/column? i would like to dispay all rows and columns..it is a lot of work i agree and for the newbee as me its extra difficult... I guess you have noticed that on my poor code

Comment: JTable usually bases on an AbstractTableModel and this model allows you to select an element from a certain row at a certain column. The use of JTable is: JTable table = new JTable(myAbstractTableModel).

Comment: The only code you posted, in your question, is how you read two text files that were selected by the user via `JFileChooser`. As I understand it, you basically want someone to provide you with the code for your entire application. Since you didn't describe how you want to display the data from the two files in a `JTable`, I would claim that it is impossible to provide the code because you haven't completely described the requirements. I think this question should be closed but because you have created a bounty, SO prevents it from being closed.

Comment: What does "union them by row" mean?
Union is a combination of all values from both "tables". In your use case this doesn't make good sense as it would be a mixed list of motors and cars. So I guess you want a JOIN. Which motor belongs to which car - do you want to JOIN by name? Or do you need a cartesian product? Also the rows column is very confusing as I guess you wanted to write column. The DDL is very confusing. Maybe get things fixed, split questions and ask again and you'll get a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with GUI programs I suggest following the MVC paradigm where all GUI components located at the Gui class. Controller class receiving GUI calls and save them in models and update GUI calls from models.

For your convenience use NetBeans IDE there you have integrated Visual GUI builder

I am intentionally omitting source code examples, because as you can see, you will need a pretty few examples, From the following topics:

**GUI**
The class extends from javax.swing.JFrame

**Controller**
Will implement all the listeners like ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener and will init all Models. Will sync from GUI to Model

**Models**
One of the Models is TableModel
To create a custom TableModel simply extend your class from AbstractTableModel and override methods use a 2-dimensional array to store table data.

**Download file**
To download data from the Model to a file you will need to create a Java object and implement a Serializable interface

**To save as Java**

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);

        out.writeObject(cars);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CarCatalog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```